# Copy from a range of cells, defined on execution, the cells that match an interior color (ExcelVBA)

Tags: excel, vba, range, countif, autofilter

My problem while using Excel VBA is trying to verify if there are cells of a certain color in a sheet of a workbook (workbookB) before applying  a filter by color (RGB(1, 255, 1)) on a sheet (SheetNameFromArray) and then copy the visible cells to another workbook (workbookA) sheet with the same name (SheetNameFromArray).

The solution I tried involved using "Application.CountIf(range, condition)" to count the cells that had the color RGB(1, 255, 1) and then if there are cells with the color, proceed to filter and copy. But, for some reason, it seems to not count the cells properly because it never copies any cell even when the sheet has cells with that color inside the range (see example below):

```
    LastSheetRow = Workbooks(WorkbookB).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastSheetColumn = Workbooks(WorkbookB).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    WorkbookALastSheetRow = Workbooks(WorkbookA).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim rngWorkbookBToCopy As Range, rngWorkbookAToPaste As Range
    With Workbooks(WorkbookB).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray)
        Set rngWorkbookBToCopy = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(LastSheetRow, LastSheetColumn - 1))
    End With
    With Workbooks(WorkbookA).Sheets(RevisionSheetNameFromArray)
        Set rngWorkbookAToPaste = .Cells(WorkbookALastSheetRow, 1)
    End With

    If Application.CountIf(rngWorkbookBToCopy, RGB(1, 255, 1)) = 0 Then
    Else
        With Workbooks(WorkbookB).Worksheets(RevisionSheetNameFromArray)
            .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastSheetRow, LastSheetColumn)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(1, 255, 1), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
        End With            
        rngWorkbookBToCopy.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy rngWorkbookAToPaste           
    End If
```

What I would like to do is copy only the range of rows that have at least a cell colored in RGB(96, 255, 210). I added the condition to check if there are cells of the said color because if the sheet didn't have cells, an error of range Autofilter property appeared. But, as I said, it seems to not count the cells properly and I am not sure about how to solve it.

Please help me and thanks in advance (& sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround based on [this post at Microsoft support.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2815384/count-the-number-of-cells-with-specific-cell-color-by-using-vba)

One has to create a function that receives the range of cells to be analyzed and the criteria of the interior color of the cells that one wants to count. This function behaves is some way as what the CountIf was expected to do for the question post (count the cells that have a certain interior color).

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria As Long) As Long
    Dim datax As Range
    Dim xcolor As Long
    xcolor = criteria
    For Each datax In range_data
        If datax.Interior.Color = xcolor Then
            CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
        End If
    Next datax
End Function
```

Applying this change, the code now would be as follows:

```
LastSheetRow = Workbooks(WorkbookB).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastSheetColumn = Workbooks(WorkbookB).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

WorkbookALastSheetRow = Workbooks(WorkbookA).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim rngWorkbookBToCopy As Range, rngWorkbookAToPaste As Range
With Workbooks(WorkbookB).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray)
    Set rngWorkbookBToCopy = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(LastSheetRow, LastSheetColumn - 1))
End With
With Workbooks(WorkbookA).Sheets(RevisionSheetNameFromArray)
    Set rngWorkbookAToPaste = .Cells(WorkbookALastSheetRow, 1)
End With

If CountCcolor(rngWorkbookBToCopy, RGB(1, 255, 1)) = 0 Then
Else
    With Workbooks(WorkbookB).Worksheets(RevisionSheetNameFromArray)
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastSheetRow, LastSheetColumn)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(1, 255, 1), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
    End With            
    rngWorkbookBToCopy.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy rngWorkbookAToPaste           
End If
```

I hope it helps other people that may encounter this situation.